# Create Gridview totally programatically in asp.net c# 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to create more than one gridview. And i want to add them from code behind(.cs) file.
Here is my code which is almost worked. But can anyone find whats an issue with this?

**sample.aspx:**

```
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
           <%CreateGridView();%>
    </form>
    </body>
```

**Sample.aspx.cs:**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected GridView CreateGridView()
    {
    GridView gv = new GridView();
    gv.ID = "_gridview1";
    Queue q = new Queue();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        q.Enqueue(i);
    gv.DataSource = q;
    gv.DataBind();
    gv.Visible = true;
    return gv;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Switch to MVC.  Control generation is much easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Sample.aspx:**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:PlaceHolder id="ph" runat="server"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Sample.aspx.cs:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.ID = "_gridview" + i;
        Queue q = new Queue();
        q.Enqueue(i);
        gv.DataSource = q;
        gv.DataBind();
        ph.Controls.Add(gv);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - This was exactly the approach I was thinking as a "safer approach"

Comment: As you mentioned @DavidStratton the `Page_Init` might be better!

Answer (score 2):

> But can anyone find whats an issue with this?

- If the GridView will be editable, you'll lose your user's changes on each postback. (Usability/functionality break)
- It won't persist to the Viewstate and the grids will need to be rebuilt on every page postback.  (Performance issue)

A safer approach may be to add an asp:Panel (sat you call it GridViewPlaceHolderPanel) to the page, and in the Page_Init event, build your GridView in code behind and add it using

GridViewPlaceHolderPanel.Controls.Add(gv);

***However***, if the two issues I listed aren't concerns (It won't be editable and you want it to be built on every postback) then your approach should work fine.

Comment: Safer approach shown perfectly in code in @JP Hellemons answer